# I need a table in Outlook exported in _simple_ html so I can use it in Javadoc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, java, html, javadoc

For documentation purposes I would like to replicate a table I received in an email in Outlook in my program that implements the information in the table.

As this is Java, that means javadoc which in turn means as simple HTML as possible.  I tried some various export possibillities like Export to HTML in Outlook, and copy-pasting the table into Excel and then export that.  So far the options I've tried creates non-trivial HTML (probably to allow for auto-updating and more) so I look for another approach.  All I need is a simple `<table><tr><td>....` thing.

I have Windows 10, MacOS and Linux available.   Please only suggest things you've actually tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by thims (https://superuser.com/a/1404887/7401) got me going.

Unfortunately, even the filtered HTML export in Word was still too verbose for my purposes.  I ended up using https://www.r2h.nl/html-word-excel-table-code-cleaner/index.php which did most of the work and then removed a lot of newlines afterwards and added a `border=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy-paste the table to **Word** rather than to Excel and then use Word's File -> Save As -> Browse -> Save as type: Web Page, Filtered.

Comment: A  good suggestion, but it did still have a lot of CSS in it.  I ended up using https://www.r2h.nl/html-word-excel-table-code-cleaner/index.php to get a plain table and then removed a lot of newline.  Your suggestion got me going.  Thanks.